# Display string horizontally or in row Java

Tags: java

So I am working on a slot machine on Java using only the console. I have some strings with ASCII word art that must be displayed on blocks of three, horizontally, like a slot machine.

```
    static final String pera = "  (     \n  / \\  \n (   ) \n  `\"' \n       \n";
    static final String platan = "       \n ,     \n \\`.__.\n  `._,'\n       \n";
    static final String raim = " \\     \n ()() \n()()()\n ()() \n  ()  \n";
    static final String kiwi = "       \n,=.    \n(.`:) \n `-'         \n";
    static final String penaut = " ,+.   \n((|)) \n )|(  \n((|)) \n `-'  ";
```

So right now this is the output
[image]
And I need it to look like this target output
[image]
The problem is that the strings I'm using are not just 1 line strings, so the usuall methods to print on the same line doesn't work, like using print instead of println. Is this even possible to program on java?

Complete code:

```
package Escurabutxaques;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Escurabutxaques {
    static boolean correcte = false;
    static String res1 = "";
    static String res2 ="";
    static String res3 = "";
    static final String pera = "  (     \n  / \\  \n (   ) \n  `\"' \n       \n";
    static final String platan = "       \n ,     \n \\`.__.\n  `._,'\n       \n";
    static final String raim = " \\     \n ()() \n()()()\n ()() \n  ()  \n";
    static final String kiwi = "       \n,=.    \n(.`:) \n `-'         \n";
    static final String penaut = " ,+.   \n((|)) \n )|(  \n((|)) \n `-'  ";
    public static void main (String[] Args){
        System.out.println("Benvingut a la màquina escurabutxaques de l'Andreu!");
        Random();
    }
    public static void Random() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            String print = "";
            Random r = new Random();
            int randomNumber = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 5 + 1);
            if (randomNumber == 1) {
                print = pera;
                switch (i){
                    case 1:
                        res1 = print;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        res2 = print;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        res3 = print;
                        break;
                }
            } else if (randomNumber == 2) {
                print = raim;
                switch (i){
                    case 1:
                        res1 = print;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        res2 = print;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        res3 = print;
                        break;
                }
            } else if (randomNumber == 3) {
                print = platan;
                switch (i){
                    case 1:
                        res1 = print;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        res2 = print;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        res3 = print;
                        break;
                }
            } else if (randomNumber == 4) {
                print = kiwi;
                switch (i){
                    case 1:
                        res1 = print;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        res2 = print;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        res3 = print;
                        break;
                }
            } else if (randomNumber == 5) {
                print = penaut;
                switch (i){
                    case 1:
                        res1 = print;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        res2 = print;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        res3 = print;
                        break;
                }
            };
            System.out.println(print);
            Random();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything it's possible to program in Java but show us your code, then we will be able to find a bug.

Comment: You could save the texts in a `String[]` instead of a single `String` and then print the fragments of the same level in a line.

Comment: How do you wanna do? Not optimal but simple or optimal and sudo-graphical?

Comment: I would like it more simple but not optimal, im starting out this year with java so i can't aim that high

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to print three different things, and each thing is going to take up multiple rows, and you want the three things to appear side by side.  There is a way to do this:

1. make sure each of your possible items to show is built of the same number of rows, and each row is of the same width
2. build each item as an array of strings, where each string in the array is one of the required rows of symbols:

```
String[] apple = new String[5];
apple[0] = ",./.,/";
apple[1] = "/dkj/!";
etc
```

or whatever the apple looks like.

3. run code to determine which three items should be displayed, e.g. apple banana apple
4. write an output builder which knows at the start what three things it needs to put together, in this case an apple followed by a banana followed by another apple.  This output builder will return an array of Strings, where row in the array is composed of the corresponding rows from the component objects.

```
String[] outputToDisplay = new String[5];
outputToDisplay[0] = apple[0] + banana[0] + apple[0];
outputToDisplay[1] = apple[1] + banana[1] + apple[1];
etc
```

You may wish to insert a blank space between each item in each row.

5. print the output

Comment: It worked for me! I had to tweak the last part a bit to get the desire outcome tho, this is what I did: 
`
String[] imprimir = new String[1];
imprimir[0] = res1[0] + res2[0] + res3[0];
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(imprimir));
imprimir[0] = res1[1] + res2[1] + res3[1]; `
` 
Thank u so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm identifying that it seems that every fruit String object is composed of 7 characters before it goes onto the next line. What you could do is simply take out the first 7 characters of the first fruit, then go on to the next fruit and take out the next 7 characters of the next fruit and concatenate these two Strings together. Keep on continuing this until you've reached the final fruit. You can then save the String which represents the first line in an array. Then you can simply move on the next 7 characters(a.k.a the second line) and repeat the process all over again. After you've gone through **all** the fruits, simply print out the string array.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ANSI cursor movement](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html).
Here is an example code to print two slots.
After understanding the trick, you can easily expand it to print three slots.

```
private static void printSlots(String slot1, String slot2) {
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;
    for (String line : slot1.split("\n")) {
        System.out.println(line);
        m = m > line.length() ? m : line.length();
        n += 1;
    }
    
    System.out.print("\033[" + n + "A");  // ANSI cursor movement to up
    for (String line : slot2.split("\n")) {
        System.out.print("\033[" + m + "C");  // ANSI cursor movement to right
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

After printing `n` lines, it goes back. Then, it print each line of next slot with left `m` paddings.